# Weblogic Session Timeout Redirect to Login Page

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

My App is a HTML and JS Based. I'm using form based auth j_security_check.
The Login and Logout works are expected.

But upon session timeout, If I request a JS file, the Login Page comes in the Content area and upon success login the JS code is displayed in the UI.

I've a filter in place but even when the session is timed out

```
if (session != null && !session.isNew())
```

returns

```
true
```

1) How do I do a proper redirect to login page ?

2) If filter is the answer, why is my session still present? Is it due to JSESSIONID ? How do I satisfy my session check and do a req dispatch to login page?

Filter Code

```
if (session != null && !session.isNew()){
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}else{
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/login.html?sTimedOut=true").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Yes, My JS and CSS is restricted. I'm still not clear what u meant by "ambiguous"? 

What I meant by JS is displayed means, the CODE is show rather than the output. I hope I'm clear now?

Comment: Login Page and it's CSS including the Images is not restricted. How can one restrict that?

Comment: The issue is with Session timeout redirect rather than accessibility.

Comment: If you are using spring security you can set the logouturl property http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is,

Have a session timeout logic in Javascript and keep checking every sec for if event for mouse click else key press, if not redirect to login page.